# Php Curl script to Post Data to API

Tags: php, curl

My requirement is to write a curl script in PHP page to post data in to external API. I have managed to write a script but i don't know is it the way to pass session parameter as header. Am getting auth failure with my code sample. Please help me to fix the issue. Thanks

```
$sessionID = 's%3A1pdDOimttaCJ1CwgtCxXDUQx.rH79R87KzV9QWFFOYQwKDaxT2Nu8zhBerDxjs2y0JiM';
$post_id = 'gmXmJiVDSgSB6BRrkbkLdA';
$approval_status = 'approved';
$data = array(
    'approval_status'=> $approval_status,
    'post_id' => $post_id
);
$session = array (
    'sessionID' => $sessionID
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $session);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.2.2:7082/approve-posts" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "response". $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How does the API say that you should pass the session id?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` value should be an array. Also `$sessionID` must be in `HeaderName: HeaderValue` format

Comment: What API is it? If we know that, we can probably try and access the documentation to give you a better answer

Comment: @KyleO'Brien Its not an external API, its created by myself. Am accessing the api using REST Client. There am setting the session as a Header variable. So i expect by calling the api via curl i should pass the session as header.

Answer (score 0):

With **CURLOPT_POST** the third parameter is query string.

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, http_build_query($data));

and with **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** the third parameter is number of fields in post data.

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));